# A Question About Sampling

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I have a large population of size *n* from an unknown continuous random variable *X*, and I do not know the underlying distribution of *X*. Suppose that I know the minimum sample size *b* required to approximate pdf of random variable *X*. What is the best way to choose these *b* samples from *n*? 
I searched on the internet and I found a few number of [sampling methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28statistics%29#Sampling_methods). but I do not know which one is more suitable. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'd use all available samples, especially if you're doing nonparametric density estimation (which you appear to be doing)... but if you have to sample a minimal subset then simple random sampling with replacement would generate a sample of size b of iid random values from the unknown distribution. If n is indeed vary large, then this random sample should very well approximate sampling from the entire population.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a reason why simple random sampling with replacement works?

Comment: @Alex because your subsample will be comprised of iid draws from the underlying distribution and so will be representative if that population

Answer (score 1):

Like Eurapraxis said, simple random sampling should suffice. Generally speaking a sample size of b=30 should suffice no matter what X is. (See Chebyshev's rule).

(And if it needs mentioning, I'm assuming here that n is significantly larger than 30.)

Comment: N= 30 is a general rule for approximating the distribution of a sample average statistic but the op wants to estimate an entire density, apparently without an underlying parametric model so a lot of data is needed